# I put the search function in the recyclerView. Items are not only seen as new data, but new data seems to be filled up a little on old data. in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

Pressing the search button in Main Activity changes the values of the items in RecyclerView.
The problem is that the existing data remains except for the newly retrieved data.
How can I show you only the new values on the list?

[image]

--- MainActivity.kt ----

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var toolbar: Toolbar
    private var logTag : String? = "로그 MainActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(logTag,"onCreate is called")

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = binding.root
        toolbar = binding.searchToolbar

        setContentView(view)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView
        val navController : NavController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.A, R.id.B, R.id.C
            )
        )


        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)

        binding.btnSearch.setOnClickListener {

            val recordFragment = RecordFragment()
            val bundle = Bundle()

            if ( binding.etSearch.text.toString() ==""|| binding.etSearch.text.isEmpty()) {
                bundle.putString("parameter", "A")
            }else {
                bundle.putString("parameter", binding.etSearch.text.toString())
            }
            recordFragment.arguments = bundle

            this.supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, recordFragment).commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {

        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.record_app_bar, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.item_search -> {
                when (binding.loSearch.visibility) {
                    GONE -> binding.loSearch.visibility = VISIBLE
                    VISIBLE -> binding.loSearch.visibility = GONE
                    else -> {
                        Log.d(logTag, "onOptionsItemSelected is called // error")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

```
class RecordFragment : Fragment() {

    private var rRecyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    private val rApi: ApiInterface? = HttpClient.getRetrofit()?.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    private var EventName : String? = null
    var logTag : String? = "로그 RecordFragment"

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_record, container, false)
        EventName = arguments?.getString("parameter")
        if (EventName == null||EventName =="") {
            EventName = ""
        }

        rRecyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recordRecyclerView)
        rRecyclerView?.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        val rAdapter = Radapter()
        rRecyclerView?.adapter = rAdapter

        //쿼리 값을 Map 으로 생성하여 api 호출
        val queries = mapOf("parameter" to EventName)

        val call: Call<Record?>? = rApi!!.getRecordData(queries)

        call?.enqueue(object : Callback<Record?> {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<Record?>,
                response: retrofit2.Response<Record?>
            ) {
                //응답 성공시 어댑터에 결과 전달
                val result: Record = response.body() as Record
                Log.d(logTag, "onResponse: refresh 직전")

                rAdapter.setList(result.data)
                rAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                //rAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, result.data?.size!!);

            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Record?>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("D/OkHttp", "onFailure - message=" + t.message)
            }
        })

        return root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {

        super.onDestroyView()
        rRecyclerView?.adapter = null
        rRecyclerView = null
    }

    inner class Radapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecordFragment.Radapter.RvhItem>() {

        private var showMatchCount: Int? = 0
        private var matchCount: Int? = 0
        private var mRecord: ArrayList<Event>? = ArrayList()

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RvhItem {

            val vhView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.vh_record, parent, false)
            return RvhItem(vhView)
        }

        @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
        fun setList(Data: List<Event>?) {

            mRecord!!.clear()
            mRecord!!.addAll(Data!!)
            notifyDataSetChanged()

        }

        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RvhItem, position: Int) {

            val record: Event = mRecord!![position]
            holder.EventName.text = record._event_name
            holder.EventDate.text = record._event_date
            showMatchCount = record._event_count?.toInt()

            matchCount = record._event_result!!.size


        }

        override fun getItemCount(): Int {

            return mRecord!!.size
        }

        inner class RvhItem(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            var EventName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_event_name)
            var EventDate: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_fighter_ranking)


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Zain, I am very grateful for the correction of my post to look good.
In fact, I tried a few times because I wanted to put the codes well in the tag after seeing the post, but it was not saved due to an error.
So I saved TAG in a weird state. revised it for me.
I want to change the title, so I'm going to change it.
"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details."
It is not saved with the phrase.
I want to know how to save it without errors.
It may not be accurately conveyed because it is written through a translator. I ask for your understanding.

Comment: You're did a good job.. You can notice the changes on the posts, by hitting [edited link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69485485/revisions) that is close to the bottom of your question.. This will enrich your ability on writing posts.. Good luck in solving it!